# Clipping planes at runtime on three js

Tags: three.js

I would like to implement clipping planes on three js.
I am not interested in a global clipping plane , but rather a local one.
Here's the code I am using :

```
switch(this.data.Axis){
   case 'X' : 
        this.clippingplane = new THREE.Plane(new THREE.Vector3(-1 , 0 , 0) , this.data.Slide) ; 
   break ; 


   case 'Y' :
   this.clippingplane = new THREE.Plane(new THREE.Vector3(0 , -1 , 0) , this.data.Slide) ; 
   break ; 

   case 'Z' :
   this.clippingplane = new THREE.Plane(new THREE.Vector3(0 , 0 , -1) , this.data.Slide) ; 
   break ; }
obj.traverseBreadthFirst(function(node){
        if(node instanceof THREE.Mesh){

            node.material.clipShadows = true ; 
            node.material.clippingPlanes = [] ; 
            node.material.clippingPlanes .push( this.clippingplane ); 
            node.material.needsUpdate = true ; 

        }
    });
```

the problem here is that javascript is returning an error :

> t is undefined

using the same code for a global clipping plane , set in the renderer , works fine... what's the issue here ?

Comment: Whatever t may be (it's absolutely impossible to tell from what you've posted), it seems that it's undefined. Javascript throws an error and can't proceed with the rest of your code.

Comment: @pailhead I think you're right .
I just changed this.clippingplane by a local variable , and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Try this general method and apply it to your example

```
var localPlane = new THREE.Plane( new THREE.Vector3( 0, 0, -1 ), 0.9 );
var material2 = new THREE.PointsMaterial( { size: 0.06, vertexColors: THREE.VertexColors, 
            clippingPlanes: [ localPlane ],
            clipShadows: true 
        } );
var points2 = new THREE.Points( geometry, material2 );
```

and then add your scene